# How to calculate ratio with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset which looks like:

```
New_ID  loanid  RPC RPC_PERIOD  PhoneNumber
0   1282908.0   10321436    0   0   9.055100e+10
1   1282908.0   10321436    0   0   9.059893e+10
2   1282908.0   10321436    0   0   9.570575e+12
3   1282908.0   10321436    0   0   9.057456e+10
4   1282908.0   10321436    0   0   9.570551e+12
```

Variable RPC is binary (1, 0).

I want to group the dataframe by "New_ID" a add new columns with total number of RPC, sum RPC (meaning to count RPC=1) a make a ratio of those two attribute.

I tried:

```
df['picked_up'] = df.groupby(by='New_ID')['RPC'].sum()
df['tries'] = df.groupby(by='New_ID')['RPC'].count()
df['ratio'] = df['picked_up'] / df['tries']
```

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: In theory you should create a new dataframe with this information instead of adding the same values to all the rows with same `New_ID`. Then if you need to pick up information contained in the other dataframe you can retrieve them using the `join` method.

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco I tried this but the rows does not align.

Comment: provide a reproducible example (possibly with more duplicates `New_ID` values) and I'll show you.

Comment: please include your expected output to help us understand your question better

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('New_ID')['RPC'].transform(sum)
df['total'] = df.groupby('New_ID')['RPC'].transform('count')
df['ratio'] = df.groupby('New_ID')['RPC'].transform(mean)
```